# Layouts get additional border

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to get a full width image / photo gallery with isotope. My problem is that Isotope adds some additional pixels around each image when it's loaded for the first time, so there is a black border around each image. When I resize my window the borders disappear and when I resize it back to full screen it's also showing without borders.

I just want to get the images side by side without any kind of border, but everything I try isn't working.

You can see it running here: [link](http://www.martijnbastiaansen.nl/testing/)

html code:

```
<div class="isotope">
    <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-200-200-4.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="stad"/></div>
    <div class="item med"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-200-200-5.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="beest"/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-200-200-5.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="stad"/></div>
    <div class="item large"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-400-400-6.jpg" width="400" height="400" alt="beest"/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-200-200-4.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="beest"/></div>
    <div class="item med"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-200-200-10.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="stad"/></div>
    <div class="item large"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-400-400-7.jpg" width="400" height="400" alt="beest"/></div>
    <div class="item med"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-200-200-9.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="stad"/></div>
    <div class="item med"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-200-200-2.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="beest"/></div>
    <div class="item large"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-400-400-8.jpg" width="400" height="400" alt="stad"/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-200-200-6.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="stad"/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-200-200-3.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="beest"/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-200-200-7.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="stad"/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-200-200-1.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="beest"/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-200-200-1.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="stad"/></div>
</div>
```

javascript code:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

    var $container = $('.isotope').imagesLoaded( function() {
        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.item',
            layoutMode: 'packery'
        });
    });  
});
```

css code:

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    background: #000;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.isotope {
    width: 100%;
}

/* ---- .item ---- */

.grid-sizer {
    width: 10%;
}

.item {
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    height: auto;
    background: #000;
    border: 0;
}

.item.med {
    width: 20%;
    height: auto;
}

.item.large { 
    width: 40%;
    height: auto; 
}

.item img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

The width of the html elements is correct, but when I check the css in the browser Isotope adds some pixels extra to the left and top positions of the elements. Hopefully someone can help me out?

Edit:

It looks like it's working fine on mobile and tablets. Maybe it has something to do with

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in the html header?

Comment: Have you tried it without imagesLoaded? Does it still do the same? I suspect that's the issue

Comment: Didn't work. imagesLoaded is needed, otherwise the lay-out is messed up because there is no height of the elements. With imagesLoaded isotope just renders when all images are loaded and all elements has the width and height settings

Comment: Yeah I get that - I'm guessing you don't have the image dimensions

Comment: Only a maximum width and height, but the rendering of the height depends on the width so I can't take a fixed dimensions. And the problem was with the isotope layout option. The problem exists when I had take out the imagesLoaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be a solution so much as a work around, but I've played around with this for awhile, and it looks like you may simply need to call [Isotope layout](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#layout) after the container is initialized. I don't know why that is, which is why this isn't a real solution.

Here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pixelsmith/pkL4d0z3/). I updated the jQuery to this, eliminating 'packery' since it kept giving me an error in the fiddle:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

var $container = $('.isotope')
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        // layoutMode: 'packery'
    });

$container.isotope('layout');
```

});`

One more thing to consider if you're going to be using percentages for the columns is using the Masonry layout and [setting explicit values for your column widths](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html#columnwidth).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Pixelsmith for pointing me in the right direction. I need to change your jQuery a bit, but calling the isotope layout did the trick for most of the part. My jquery is looking like this now:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

    $('.isotope').imagesLoaded( function() {
        var $container = $('.isotope');
        $container.isotope({
            layoutMode: 'packery',
            packery: {
                columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
            },
            itemSelector: '.item'
        });
        $container.isotope('layout');
    });
});
```

Calling imagesLoaded, so width and height of elements are correct and isotope is function well. For my project packery is better then masonry, because packery is filling up all gaps, masonry is just looking for the first possible gap and doesn't fill empty gaps.

Comment: Great to hear you worked it out! I realize now that Packery requires an extra package, which is why it wasn't working for me. I'm still intrigued as to why that second call is necessary, but perhaps someone with greater jQuery/Isotope skill can fill me in someday.

Comment: I think somewhere an element is changing while Isotope is loading, so the layout needs to be calculated again. When I open my testing site now, first I see the borders and in a split second I see the images moving closer to each others.